# How to confirm that computation uses multiple CPUs?

Tags: parallelization

UPDATE: I should have made clear that I'm looking preferably for solutions that work on a text-only interface.  I've fixed this omission below.

---

I'm looking for some *Mathematica* **expression** whose evaluation would

1. be amenable to the text-only interface<sup>1</sup>;
2. require several minutes to complete; and
3. result from roughly equal amounts of work from multiple CPUs?

...together with some way to confirm that condition (3) holds?

---

On my desktop, using the text-only interface, `$ProcessorCount` evaluates to `4`, so I tried the following (still in the text-only interface):

```
test = Function[x, If[PrimeQ[x], x, $Failed]];
offset = 10^100;
length = 10^8;
range = Range[offset, offset + length];
wanted = 10^5;

found = ParallelTry[test, range, wanted] - offset;
```

Shortly after the evaluation of the last expression started, *Mathematica* printed the message

```
Launching kernels...
```

So far so good.  And in fact, at this point the number of `WolframKernel` processes shown by the `top` utility went from 1 to 5.  Nevertheless, only one of them did any significant work.  The screenshot below was entirely typical:

[image]

---

FWIW, here are some details on the hardware I ran the above on::

```
% lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v3 @ 3.50GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               1402.050
CPU max MHz:           3600.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              6983.85
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              10240K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>In my desktop machine, I am not limited to *Mathematica*'s text-only interface, but ultimately I want to use this expression to troubleshoot a remotely running instance of *Mathematica*, and for the latter only the text-only interface is available.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the graphical interface, try looking up the help page for `CompilationTarget` and open "Neat Examples". Run the commands there and you'll get a nice interactive Mandelbrot set explorer in which you can zoom using a slider and move using mouse drag. You can make this arbitrarily hard by changing the constant 99 to, say, 5000 in the first evaluated line (definition of `mandelComp`). Zoom so that the whole area is painted in black, which requires the maximum number of iterations for each pixel. Now open `top` and watch the percentages when you drag the image around, causing it to recompute whenever a new queued event is processed. I could easily get close to 400% CPU on my 4-processor machine.

The information there, and in the linked pages (especially the "Related guides"), will help you learn how to write your own multi-CPU-parallelized code.

Comment: The help page for `CompilationTarget` is also available [online](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationTarget.html). In a text-only interface one could still define `mandelComp` and evaluate it on a large table of points.

Comment: @Rahul: thanks for the idea for the text-only interface; my original write-up of the question failed to make this requirement clear (I've now fixed this).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) in the terminal to confirm that given Mathematica task is using multiple cores. I use htop all the time to monitor CPU and memory usage.